# Does 'accepting' an answer ever lock in?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I have a question about 'accepting' an answer. From what I have come to know, the original poster can accept an answer, but change it, too. Is there a point at which the user can no longer change which answer is accepted?

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: Well, if the askers no longer has access to the account (for example, it's been deleted) then they can't change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a word - no. Answers can always be "unaccepted", and different answers to the question accepted.